# Unable to use Pen tablet as Monitor

Tags: ubuntu, multi-monitor, mirror

I am not able to mirror the screen in my XP pen tablet in ubuntu. When i open my Pen tab software, it is showing like this:
[image]

Where as in windows it is working fine as shown below:

[image]

What might be the issue in Ubuntu?

Comment: Looks like the tablet (which model exactly?) gets the screen image with a HDMI or USB-C connection. Which kind of connection are you using? Does your desktop environment see the tablet as a display device? You might need to configure the desktop environment to mirror the display image to the tablet yourself, as the display configuration interface in Linux is not as uniform as in Windows. If your computer (make and model?) is a laptop with two GPUs, that might cause some extra complications too.

Comment: XP pen artist 15.6, thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

The driver installation instructions for Windows have these steps:

> 5. In [Control Panel] > [Display], change your dual monitor settings to Extend mode/Extend these displays.
> 6. In Extend mode, set your Artist 15.6 to monitor 2 and choose a resolution of 1920x1080.
> 7. In Duplicate these displays mode, set both of your monitors’ resolutions to 1920x1080.

Have you done the equivalent steps in Ubuntu's GNOME Control Center?

To directly open the appropriate part of the GNOME Control Center, you could enter this command into a command prompt:

```
gnome-control-center display
```

Comment: should we type this in terminal?

Comment: Typing `gnome-control-center display` is just a shortcut to directly open the GNOME display settings window; you don't have to use it if you find your way into the display settings using the mouse. But if you are uncertain, type that into a terminal and it will open the display settings window for you.

Comment: @telecoM, tq for the reply, but what i did is , i uninstalled ubuntu and installed Ubuntu 22.10(Latest). I will update whether Xp pen pro works in it with a new post